# Attempting to drop packets to simulate a network failure

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking, switch

I have a switch running Linux with multiple devices on it.
I'm attempting to simulate a network outage on one of the devices.

I've attempted to drop the packets with both netem and iptables using either one of the commands:

`tc qdisc add dev <interface> root netem loss 100%`

or

`iptables -A INPUT -i <interface> -p all -j DROP`

However, the device stays connected.

Any ideas?

Comment: a switch is a layer 2 device, mostly a piece of hardware. linux with iptables firewall operates at layer 3. what does "devices on it" mean? are there hardware servers/VMs connected to that switch?

Comment: Unplug patch cable? Disable port? Put port in a VLAN by itself? Ain't so hard really...